# Likelihood Estimation on ARCH process

Tags: partial-derivative, time-series

on the seminal paper of Robert Engle about Arch Process ([Engle, R. F. (1982). Autoregressive conditional heteroscedasticity with estimates of the variance of United Kingdom inflation. Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society, 987-1007.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1912773)) the first order conditions for maximum likelihood estimation for an ARCH(1) process is derived. Consider the next statements:

\begin{equation}
y_t = \epsilon_t\cdot h_t^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
h_t = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 \cdot y_{t-1}^2
\end{equation}

Where $E{[}\epsilon_t{]}=0$ and $Var{[}\epsilon_t{]}=1$. Now, the log-likelihood estimator of $\alpha$ named $l_t$ is:

\begin{equation}
l_t = -\frac{1}{2} log\, h_t - \frac{1}{2} \frac{y_t^2}{h_t}
\end{equation}

where $log\,x$ is the natural logarithm of $x$. Well, the paper state that the first order conditions for the likelihood estimation are:

\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial l_t}{\partial \alpha} = \frac{1}{2h_t} \frac{\partial h_t}{\partial \alpha} \left(\frac{y_t^2}{h_t} - 1\right)
\end{equation}

along with the Hessian. My question is how get the expression for $ \frac{\partial l_t}{\partial \alpha}$ from $l_t$? I tried to deduce the expression but I get a different result. In the calculation of the partial derivative of $y_t^2$ with respect to $\alpha$, is $y_t$ treated as independent of $\alpha$? and if the answer is yes why is that? (considering that $y_t = \epsilon_t \cdot h_t^{\frac{1}{2}}$ where $h_t$ itself depends on $\alpha$).

In advance, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, checking my calculations after a long time, there's the answer. First, the model used is:

\begin{align}
y_t | \psi_{t-1} &\sim \mathcal{N}(0, h_t)\\
h_t &= \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 y_{t-1}^2 \\
h_t &= h(y_{t-1}, y_{t-2}, \ldots,y_{t-p}, \alpha)
\end{align}

where $p$ is the order of the process. As you can see $y_t$ **is not equal to** $\epsilon_t \cdot h^{1/2}$. So:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial{h_t}}{\partial\alpha} &= - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial{log(h_t)}}{\partial\alpha} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial{\frac{y^2_t}{h_t}}}{\partial\alpha}\\
\frac{\partial{h_t}}{\partial\alpha} &= - \frac{1}{2 h_t} \frac{\partial{h_t}}{\partial\alpha} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{-y^2_t}{h^2_t} \frac{\partial h_t}{\partial \alpha}\\
\frac{\partial{h_t}}{\partial\alpha} &= - \frac{1}{2 h_t} \frac{\partial{h_t}}{\partial\alpha} \left(1 - \frac{y^2_t}{h^2_t}\right) \\
\frac{\partial{h_t}}{\partial\alpha} &= \frac{1}{2 h_t} \frac{\partial{h_t}}{\partial\alpha} \left(\frac{y^2_t}{h^2_t} - 1\right)
\end{align}

which is the expression needed.